# Embed power bi report in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi, sign

I'm  trying to embed power report in sharepoint, which is done successfully, however, the problem is for the end users. If anyone is trying to view the report it's requesting for a sign up. My organization doesn't allow a direct sign up,  it has to go through a IT portal and it's really not feasible to ask hundreds of end users to do that as some of them are senior management folks. Can someone please help me to resolve this

Comment: You'll have to assign them a Power BI license in the O365 portal, there is no other way. You'll have to ask the IT dept to do a bulk update of the users

Answer (score 0):

For Embed in SharePoint Online reports to work, the following is required:

1.The Power BI web part for SharePoint Online requires Modern Pages.

2.To consume an embedded report, users must sign in to Power BI service to activate their Power BI license.

3.Users need a Power BI Pro or Premium Per User (PPU) license, unless the report is hosted in a Power BI Premium capacity (EM or P SKU). In that case, users only need a free Power BI license to view reports embedded in Sharepoint Online.

Reference:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-embed-report-spo